# npm install --legacy-peer-deps fails because of of isssue with node-sass

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

I am new to node and I am trying to run a vue.js project. My node, my npm and my node-gyp version is newer than the ones the project was created with.
I was running

```
    npm install -g node-gyp
    npm install -g npm
```

because node-gyp was looking for python 2.x for sass module. But I am using python 3.x (https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1977)

Now when I run npm install --legacy-peer-deps I get the following error. Can you tell me what is the problem?

```
PS C:\projectPath> npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\projectPath\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\projectPath\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\projectPath\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "c:\python310\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded c:\python310\python.exe c:\python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: c:\python310\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:399:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\projectPath\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\projectPath\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-10T13_20_35_750Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: You should probably use the project's versions regarding the packages.

Comment: If node-gyp needs python 2 to install, you need python 2 to install. Also of note is that node-sass *is* deprecated and will not compile *at all* on some OS / hardware configurations.

Comment: @kissu what packages you mean, the npm and node-gyp versions? I didn't change any other packages.

Comment: @crashmstr on the github link they say you dont need python2 and should update npm and node-gyp

Comment: What is the project's supposed to run on? Node 16? Do you have a lockfile there? Do you have a README.md maybe? Also, I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install and manage your node.js versions. Will be far easier to deal with.

Comment: @user1664377 Did you read all of the comments? "Python 3 is now supported in both node-gyp **v5** and **v6**", and your output shows v3.8.0, so if you are not using a node-gyp that runs on Python 3, you likely need to either install Python 2 or upgrade your node-gyp. Also, reminder: node-sass is deprecated and replacements don't require node-gyp.

Comment: Likely duplicate and/or solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=node-sass+error

Comment: @crashmstr weird. I checked my node-gyp version and it says version 9.

Comment: @kissu That is the question. I only know it is an older node version than mine. in the lock file and the readme isn't anything written about the node version.

Comment: Check in `package.json`, there is maybe an `engines`. Otherwise, ask of just try `10` or `12`, or even `14`. We can't help you guess more.

Comment: @user1664377 Your error text there shows `npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0`, so there might be multiple versions installed. You do not mention node-sass at all except in the title, and it may be using a specific version of node-gyp.

Comment: @user1664377 in the errors it mentions node-sass. When removing node-sass and sass-loader from the package.json I dont get the error. How can I find out where that node-gyp@3.8.0 comes from?

Comment: @user1664377 changing node-sass to sass would migrate flawlessly? would work out of the box or would it mean that I would need to change the sass related code?

Comment: @user1664377 I migrated a project from node-sass to sass with only a few tweaks needed, and I don't know sass. The problem was that while the code would build on the server, some DEV machines would not be able to build because the node-sass was not supported on newer and 64 bit platforms.